# How to properly catch the initial response of a server?

Tags: c++, sockets, ftp, winsock, recv

My C++ program is trying to check status of a ftp-server. It uses winsock and simple testing function that looks like this (pseudocode):

```
create a tcp socket
connect to port 21 of the server
do recv() while data is available
close socket
return received data
```

It doesn't send any data to the server with send() - just trying to catch server's initial response. This actually works and returns "200 Response Server Ready" - it is exactly what I need. But after 2nd run of the same function (immediately after 1st run) it returns nothing (because recv() returns -1). Wireshark tells me the server really didn't send a response. After that I placed a half-second pause between the testing function calls and now it works, but this solution is unwanted.
The question is: How to properly catch the server's (not only ftp, but any other too) initial response?

Comment: is your recv async or blocking?

Comment: recv is blocking, and now I use setsockopt() to set recv timeout

Comment: If `recv()` returns -1, call `WSAGetLastError()` to find out why.

Comment: Oops.. I did mistake, actually recv() returns 0. It looks like I want impossible thing and this question must be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to catch answer of server. If your program connects to some port, then some server listening to this port and is OK. So just open connection and check socket variable.

PS: A lot of servers don't do anything until you send data to them (not sure about FTP), you have to send something to get answer. But to have status succesfull connection is enough.

Comment: I understand that server's behavior depends on it's implementation. Anyway I hope to find an option to force the server to make initial response...

Comment: You don't have to wait initial response, succesfull connection says that server is OK and alive.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But unfortunately an initial response is very important for me.

Comment: @OlegOlivson: some protocols, including FTP, do send an initial response immediately upon connection established, before the client sends anything. For FTP, that initial response tells the client whether the server is ready (it may tell the client to go away), and it may include data parameters necessary for some later commands.